# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't search for or connect to wireless networks

Tags: networking, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu onto my external hard drive which is fine apart from the fact it will not allow me to search for or connect to wireless networks. My internal hard drive has Windows 7 installed and the wireless works perfectly fine and always has, so I doubt it's a hardware issue. However, the Ethernet is usable as I have a Huawei mobile wifi device and USB cable and can connect to the internet using that, but its not ideal and I wish to be able to connect to my home hub while I'm using Ubuntu. The name of my wired connection is "geometric".

I ran the wireless info script and the results are here: https://pastebin.com/raw/0dzStcFa

I have tried `sudo service network-manager restart` but that didn't work. Another thread suggested adding the `SUSPEND_MODULES` line to the config file but that also didn't have any effect.

Comment: After you correct the driver, I suggest that you remove the `SUSPEND_MODULES` file. It is not needed.